# findautocompletepredictionsrequest is chargeable?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, geocoding, autocompletetextview

here my question is that [autocomplete prediction](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/android-sdk/autocomplete?hl=en_GB#get_place_predictions_programmatically) is
chargeable?
I use this method and after that get lat Lng from a suggestion (using place API ) it's cost too much high?

how can I reduce the cost? any other way to archive autocomplete suggestions?

any suggestions and sample examples will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Places SDK for Android documentation confirms that `findAutocompletePredictions()` requests are indeed billable: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/android-sdk/usage-and-billing

You can optimize the cost by using field masking to return only the [places data fields](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/place-data-fields) that you need. You can do it in Places SDK for Android by calling `setPlaceFields()` fields method that accepts an array of data fields.

For example, the code below will only return the `place_id` and the `name` of the searched place which are part of the [Basic Data](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/place-data-fields#basic). You can check the sample billable usage for `Places Autocomplete (included with Places Details) – Per Session`:  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/android-sdk/usage-and-billing#ac-with-details-session

```
autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME));
```

Comment: I already set field mask and request without place details it's still cost much more and another solution I have is that use Geocoding API so I have switched to geocoding from Place API now let's see

Comment: You can also file a support case with Google Maps Platform support team for more optimization on your API usage: https://developers.google.com/maps/support/#creating-a-support-case